# ¿como configurar fechas dinámicas en oracle 11g?

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle-11g, ascii

Estoy configurando un query para generar un informe, pero el generador de reportes solo utiliza código ascii y me da problemas con la parte de las fechas. El query que tengo es el siguiente:

```
SELECT t1.pernom||chr(9)||
   (SELECT count(t2.percod)
      FROM gx.abonad t2,
           gx.aboruc t3
     WHERE t1.percod = t2.percod
       AND t2.percod = t3.percod(+)
       AND t2.abocod = t3.abocodruc(+)
       AND t2.abosts = 'C'
       AND SUBSTR(TRIM(t2.aboruc), 1, 1) = 'J')||chr(9)||
   (SELECT count(t2.percod)
      FROM gx.abonad t2,
           gx.aboruc t3
     WHERE t1.percod = t2.percod
       AND t2.percod = t3.percod(+)
       AND t2.abocod = t3.abocodruc(+)
       AND t2.abocmsts = 'C'
       AND SUBSTR(TRIM(t2.aboruc), 1, 1) = 'J')||chr(9)||
    (SELECT count(t2.percod)
      FROM gx.abonad t2,
           gx.aboruc t3
     WHERE t1.percod = t2.percod
       AND t2.percod = t3.percod(+)
       AND t2.abocod = t3.abocodruc(+)
       AND t2.abotlfsts = 'C'
       AND SUBSTR(TRIM(t2.aboruc), 1, 1) = 'J')||chr(9)||
    (SELECT count(t2.percod)
      FROM gx.abonad t2,
           gx.aboruc t3
     WHERE t1.percod = t2.percod
       AND t2.percod = t3.percod(+)
       AND t2.abocod = t3.abocodruc(+)
       AND t2.abodthsts = 'C'
       AND SUBSTR(TRIM(t2.aboruc), 1, 1) = 'J')||chr(9)||
    sum(t6.facimplin * (1 + t6.facivaprj / 100))
FROM gx.permis t1,
   gx.abonad t4,
   gx.faccab t5,
   gx.faclab t6
WHERE t1.percod = t4.percod
 AND t4.percod = t5.percod
 AND t4.abocod = t5.abocod
 AND t5.percod = t6.percod
 AND t5.facnro = t6.facnro
 AND t5.factpo = t6.factpo
 AND t5.factpo = 'F'
 AND t5.facsts = 'P'
 AND t5.facorg IN ('D', 'M')
 AND t5.facfch >= TO_DATE('01/01/2017', 'dd/mm/yyyy')
GROUP BY t1.percod, t1.pernom
ORDER BY t1.pernnom
```

como pueden ver la condición `t5.facfch >= TO_DATE('01/01/2017', 'dd/mm/yyyy')` es la que me está causando errores en el generador de informes. He leído que se utiliza un código como `TO_DATE(TO_CHAR(LAST_DAY(ADD_MONTHS(SYSDATE, -2)) + 1,'dd/mm/yyyy'),'dd/mm/yyyy')` pero no entiendo como funciona este caso. No soy muy conocedor de este tipo de código.

ese query debe ejecutarse cada mes... por ejemplo, hoy es 8 de marzo, si ejecuto el query hoy, deben salir todos los registros almacenados desde el 1 de marzo hasta hoy, o si hoy fuese 30 de abril, el informe debe mostrar los registros desde el 1 de abril hasta 30 de abril... es decir, todos los datos desde el primer día del mes, hasta la fecha actual

Comment: No entiendo el problema. ¿Por qué estás tan seguro que el problema es `t5.facfch >= TO_DATE('01/01/2017', 'dd/mm/yyyy')`? ¿Qué error recibes? ¿Donde esta la fecha dinámica? Yo solo veo caracteres ascii, no veo el problema.

Comment: ese query debe ejecutarse cada mes... por ejemplo, hoy es 8 de marzo, si ejecuto el query hoy, deben salir todos los registros almacenados desde el 1 de marzo... y la condición que menciono, no es muy viable

Comment: Ok, creo que eso entiendo. La parte donde creo que todavía estoy confundido es, ¿qué tiene que ver lo del ascii?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Lo que entiendo es que deseas cambiar la condición siguiente:

```
AND t5.facfch >= TO_DATE('01/01/2017', 'dd/mm/yyyy')
```

... para que de forma automática o dinámica busque los registros con fecha igual o mayor al primer día del mes corriente.

La manera más sencilla que yo conozco de hacer esto en Oracle es, por supuesto,  usando `SYSDATE` para obtener la fecha corriente, y luego usando la función `TRUNC` con el parámetro `'MONTH'` para convertirlo a la fecha que corresponde al primer día del mes corriente:

```
AND t5.facfch >= TRUNC(sysdate, 'MONTH')
```

<kbd>[**Demo**](http://rextester.com/TVSBX81364)</kbd>

Comment: Muchísimas gracias bro, sirvió.